# Custom display in saved Entity reference in Widget field

Tags: nodes, hooks

We have an entity reference field widget. Based on a view where you can enter the code of a product to get to the product reference.

The widget shows the 2 fields (code) - (Title) when we type in the widget.

But after saving, only the title and the Node ID is shown. Title (nodeID)

How can I override what is displayed in the entity reference field to include my product CODE in prefix?
(code) - (Title) (nodeID)

We need this as we reference by code AND name in our industry.